# jquery cascade is acting up. All of the sudden the child and grand child does not match from edit form to view and view properties

Tags: 2010, jquery, form, cascading

I am attaching 3 print shots for editform, view properties and view. The view shows category, subgroup and subtypes which does not match edit form values. The values in the edit form are correct. What is happening? Same thing with view properties. only category is matching with edit form and rest of the values aren't. Any idea? It's has been working for last 8 months.

Here is the code

```
<script src="/_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/jquery/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({             
                relationshipList: "FAC_SubGroup",
                relationshipListParentColumn: "FAC_Category",
                relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
                parentColumn: "Category",
                childColumn: "SubGroup",
                promptText: "Choose Sub Group ...",
                debug: true
            });

            $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({             
                relationshipList: "FAC_SubTypes",
                relationshipListParentColumn: "FAC_SubGroup",
                relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
                parentColumn: "SubGroup",
                childColumn: "SubTypes",
                promptText: "Choose Sub Type ...",
                debug: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are using custom script, you will have greater chances by sharing it

Comment: my bad. just added the code in the original post. not custom code. same code that spservices provides